# asp.net newbie question - css href path

Tags: asp.net, relative-path

When start debug mode of my asp.net website, it renders in my browser with the url

```
http://localhost:111/mywebsite/Default.aspx
```

The css file is referenced like this in the html

```
<link href="~/css/style.css" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

So naturally the site breaks because it looks for the CSS file in `localhost:111/css/` instead of `localhost:111/mywebsite/css`/.

When I launch the website, it will actually be served from the url:

```
http://mywebsite.com
```

So is there a way to reference my stylesheet properly in both my dev and production area with a simple prefix like `<?=$site_url ?>` or something?

**Additional info**

In my solution explorer, I see that my project is marked with the path `C:\...\mywebsite`.  Is that why the `~` assumes my project is always in a subdirectory?  How do I tell Visual Studios that this project should always be served as something like `http://localhost:111/Default.aspx`?

This is what I see in the page source of both my localhost and production server:
`<link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>`.  The css is active on production,  but not my localhost.

Comment: The tilde(~) character is meant for referencing the root of your application, so it should render the link element correctly.  What exactly are you seeing in the page source?

Comment: I see this in the page source `<link href="~/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>`, which works on my production website, but not my localhost.

Comment: Are you sure you have the CSS folder and file on your local machine? :)

Comment: @Joe - yes i'm sure.  BEcause if i change the path to /blutip/css/style.css, then it works on localhost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went to the solution explorer, then selected the item in the tree labelled `C:\...\mywebsite`, then I went to the Properties window at bottom right of VS, and changed the Virtual path to `/`.  Now my dev website's root is the same as my prod website's root.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick.

```
<link href="<%=ResolveUrl("~/css/style.css")%>" runat="server" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: You're missing the close `"` after the sever script close tag.

Answer (score 0):

You already have, `~` resolves to the root of the website when the page is rendered.

Further reading: http://weblogs.asp.net/fmarguerie/archive/2004/05/05/avoiding-problems-with-relative-and-absolute-urls-in-asp-net.aspx (which works in chrome, FF and IE).

`~` resolves on the server (which is why you need `runat="server"`).
This code is run to generate the response from a HTTP request that has come to your dev server which is hosting the site from the location of the project on your disk.
`~` doesn't assume that the site is in a subdirectory, the dev server will know the root of the website.

In production the site is being hosted by IIS from another location on the disk of the server machine.

Comment: Hi StuperUser, that page is broken for me.  only shows an error.  I also added additional info to my Question

Answer (score -1):

Change it to:

```
<link href="/css/style.css"" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Remove **`runat="server"`** (***if you don't need it***).

Instead of **`href="~/css/style.css"`** use: **`href="/css/style.css"`**

`href="/css/style.css"` means that there is a folder named **css** in **root** of your website and a file named **style.css** inside it.

**UPDATE:**

***As pointed out by comments, this solution only works if your app is running in root.***

Comment: What if your app is not running in the web root?